# LaTeX lowercase a single letter in an makeuppercase environment

Tags: latex

I am writing a paper using the ACM template which capitalizes every letter in the section title.  I would like to escape a letter to make it lowercase, is this possible?  I tried {p} as would be done to capitalize a letter in a bibliography with no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `\lowercase{}` command to force a letter to be lowercase, a la:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\showuc}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\begin{document}
\showuc{Hello There} \\
\showuc{Hello \lowercase{T}here} \\
\showuc{Hello Th\lowercase{e}re}
\end{document}
```

If this isn't effective in conjunction with the ACM template command, could you post which ACM template and which command/environment you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic, but see if you can convince your SIG to change to the [ACM SIGPLAN LaTeX class](http://www.sigplan.org/authorInformation.htm).  It fixes a lot of things that are terribly broken in the horror that was foisted on ACM members some 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
\uppercase{xx \lowercase{x} yy}
```

Comment: `\uppercase` and `\lowercase` do not work very well in all situations, they do for example not deal very well with non-American characters. David Carlisle’s `textcase` package seems to solve many of the problems. See [Case-changing oddities](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange)